# How to make the php strings selectable for the html query?

Tags: php

I'm looking to make the the suggestions given by the Dictionary API to become links that can be queried or that are inserted directly in to the text are field before they are searched. I'm looking to achieve some kind of query expansion in any case.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Search Attempt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action='AllinOneMonstaaa.php'>
    <label for="query">Query</label><br/>
    <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" /><br /><br /> 
    <select name ="agg">
    <option value="Aggregated">Aggregated</option>
    <option value="Non-Aggregated">Non-Aggregated</option>
    <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
    <option value="Blekko">Blekko</option>
    <option value="Faroo">Faroo</option>
    </select>
    <input name="bt_search" type="submit" value="Search" /> </form>
    <h2> Results </h2>
    </body>
</html>

 <?php
 if ($_POST['query'])

 {
    $query = urlencode($_POST['query']);
    $s_count = 0;
    $ss_count = 0;
    $query = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/'.$query.'? 
    $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator(file_get_contents($query));
    foreach ($xml -> suggestion as $suggestion[$s_count])
    {
        $s_count++;
    }
    if ($s_count > 1)
    {
        echo ('<h4>Did you mean?</h4>');
        while ($ss_count <=$s_count)
        {
         echo ($suggestion[$ss_count].'<br>');
         $ss_count++;
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: from what i could understand you simply need to put an <a> tag around the suggestion

Comment: The following line is not closed correctly., I fixed it: `$query = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/'.$query.'?';`

Comment: Thanks, think that was a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Quick bug, there's a missing ' on the $query line.

```
echo '<a href="whatever">'. $suggestion[$ss_count].'<br>';
```

Edit: This will send them to Dictionary.com with the word to look up there. Outside that I have no idea how else you would formulate the url.

```
echo '<a href="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/"' . $suggestion[$ss_count] . '" target="_new">' . $suggestion[$ss_count] . '<br>';
```

Comment: That makes sense but where do I send the href to? The html is calling to itself.

Comment: Added another echo, but I'm not sure that that will answer your question or fit within the program specs since the site I used, or method of redirection, may not fit within your program specs/desires.

Comment: A yeah, thanks for the help anyhow. I'm getting closer to the answer or at least a correctly formulated question.

Comment: Glad I could help. The only thing I could think of is to load the results of recommended words into a variable and then make a link with a click event that brings up a window with the definition. I'm not savvy enough with JavaScript/CSS to even begin to help you there though.